# How to use external library in a Typescript 2.0 project?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, filesaver.js

I have a Typescript 2.0 project that uses Common JS modules and System JS loader.  I use Visual Studio code as IDE.  I am having trouble using an external library (filesaver JS) in my project.

I installed both the [library](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js) and the [type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/types-2.0/filesaver/index.d.ts) via npm.  Both appear in my node_modules and node_module/@types respectively.

How do I reference (import) the filesaver saveAs function in my TypeScript code in my function that is to save a blob (an object converted to a JSON string)?

I tried several variations of import, but none of them seems to work for me.  I get either 'index.d.ts' is not a module error, or 'module not found' error.

Here is what I tried:

`import filesaver = require('FileSaver');  //error: index.d.ts is not a module
import {FileSaver} from 'file-saver';  //error: cannot find module file-saver`

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "es2015", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "src"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Comment: Can you show your tsconfig.json (if you are using one) file, and can you provide examples of how you've tried to import it?

Comment: @DaveV - added the requested info to the question.

Comment: I spoke too soon earlier, but I think I have it working (or at least a work around).  I couldn't get an `import` to work, but I was about to do `var fileSaver = require("file-saver");` and then call `saveAs` like `fileSaver.saveAs();`

Comment: @DaveV - tried your suggestion above.  Get `fileSaver.saveAs is not a function` run-time error.

Comment: I'm at a loss then.  Looking over the type definition file, it doesn't look right (at no point does it actually call `saveAs` a function) so I'm not sure that the definition is correct.

Comment: @DaveV - OK.  Thanks for trying.  Just in case it matters, this is an Angular 2 project that uses System JS module loader.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in an Angular 2 project that uses System JS module loader.
For me

```
import {saveAs} from 'file-saver';
```

worked, but only after I explicitely set the module format of file-saver to cjs in the System JS configuration:

```
"packages":{
     "file-saver":{
          "main":"FileSaver.js", 
          "format": "cjs"
     }
}
```

As far as I understand SystemJS will recognize file-saver as AMD module by default. Maybe there is something wrong with the AMD module definition in file-saver, but I have not a very deep understanding of this. (See also https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js#L182)

Comment: P.S.: Before setting cjs mdoule format, I had also the issue `fileSaver.saveAs is not a function` as mentioned above in a comment by @ebhh2001

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the perfect solution, but the following three lines work for me in IE 11 and Chrome.

```
var saveAs = require('file-saver');
var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(myDataObject)], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
saveAs(blob, "file.txt");
```